# Why this sinatra code is not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong here. The result is empty and I'm looking it to return `hello` (calling the method `testing` through the `before`  helper).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
end

before do 
  testing
end 

def testing
  return "hello"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here. For one thing you have to actually call the output or variable you want in the view, most typically as an instance variable (otherwise every user gets the same output.) Take the modified code below for example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  @word
end

before do 
  testing
end 

def testing
  @word = "hello"
end
```

Check out the [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/), a free online resource, for information on getting started with Sinatra.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not calling the output on the Get request, you need to tell your Get Method to return an output. Like thekungfuman suggested. or try the Minimal Hello World Sinatra app as follows:

```
#imports
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

#Get Request on Root ("/")
get '/' do
    "Hello Sinatra World!"
end
```

Also it's useful to put your program under a class, so you can also do :

```
#imports
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'

#My Application Class
class AppName < Sinatra::base
    get '/' do
        'Hello Sinatra World!'
    end
end

AppName.run!
```

This way you can also use this as a seperate app file and import it within other files like.

```
require 'app_name' #replace this with the name of the physical file

#Run Application "AppName"
AppName.run!
```